# While Generating Dashboard report on non gui mode i have been getting error

Tags: jmeter

While generating Dashboard report I have been getting this error

`An error occurred: Error while processing samples: Consumer failed with message :Could not parse timeStamp <18/08/20 10:05> using format defined by property jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss on sample 18/08/20 10:05,1717`

Could someone please help me solve this?

Comment: Hi, could you provide some context? Could you show the code that was ran to cause this? I would suggest also looking at [tour] and [ask] to help you write the question better for us to be able to help easier.

Answer (score 0):

Set in user.properties:

> jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=dd/MM/yy HH:mm

And try again